# Error converting data type varchar to bigint while using LIKE Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am using the following SQL code. However I am getting the error shown. I am using Azure SQL Database

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE BIGINT 
SET @VARIABLE = 442245

SELECT * 
FROM CFG_RegionConfig 
WHERE ConfigValue LIKE '%' + @VARIABLE + '%' 
  AND ConfigKey IN ('SCMImportLinesBPC', 'CatalogSyncher1BPC', 'CatalogSyncher2BPC')
```

Error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Why do you want to use `LIKE` on a `bigint`?

Comment: There is documentation for the LIKE operator.   It states that both sides of the LIKE must be strings, not BIGINTs.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

One way around this specific problem is to use `CONCAT()`:

```
ConfigValue LIKE CONCAT('%', @VARIABLE, '%')
```

However, I find it suspicious that you want to use string operations on a number.  That suggests something is awry with the logic or data model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing with a string you need to convert the BIGINT to a string first.

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE BIGINT 
SET @VARIABLE=442245

select * from CFG_RegionConfig WHERE ConfigValue LIKE '%'+ CAST(@VARIABLE AS NVARCHAR(32)) +'%' AND ConfigKey  
IN ('SCMImportLinesBPC', 'CatalogSyncher1BPC', 'CatalogSyncher2BPC')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
SELECT * 
FROM CFG_RegionConfig 
WHERE ConfigValue LIKE '%' + CAST(@VARIABLE as NVARCHAR) + '%' 
AND ConfigKey IN ('SCMImportLinesBPC', 'CatalogSyncher1BPC', 'CatalogSyncher2BPC')
```

OR:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CFG_RegionConfig 
WHERE ConfigValue LIKE '%' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@VARIABLE) + '%' 
AND ConfigKey IN ('SCMImportLinesBPC', 'CatalogSyncher1BPC', 'CatalogSyncher2BPC')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this:

First way by declaring your variable as a `varchar(n)` and don't forgot to use the proper length as

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE VARCHAR(20) = '%442245%';

SELECT * 
FROM CFG_RegionConfig 
WHERE ConfigValue LIKE @VARIABLE
  AND ConfigKey IN ('SCMImportLinesBPC', 'CatalogSyncher1BPC', 'CatalogSyncher2BPC')
```

Second way by using [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function which will convert the datatype for you as

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE BIGINT 
SET @VARIABLE = 442245

SELECT * 
FROM CFG_RegionConfig 
WHERE ConfigValue LIKE CONCAT('%', @VARIABLE, '%') 
  AND ConfigKey IN ('SCMImportLinesBPC', 'CatalogSyncher1BPC', 'CatalogSyncher2BPC')
```

The third way by using [`CAST()/CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to covert the number into a string (varchar(n)) as provided in other answers.